# Can I try to induce a freeze in my computer to isolate what is causing freezing?

Tags: linux-kernel, freeze, testing, acer

Lately I have experienced some freezes in my laptop (Acer Aspire V 11 Touch). In all cases there were neither high loads at stake nor alleged programs (once I was even typing around simple commands in the terminal).

The issue has been severe though, since the keyword too went unresponsive, hence the solutions in the like of these https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408 are not applicable and I resorted to power off the machine brutally.

I initially blamed the upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04. However, the problem persists also after having downgraded the release to 14.04. I also noticed that one other *desktop* running on Ubuntu 14.04 has never gotten stuck. Then the release is not the culprit, seemingly.

Two features that I can recognise are common to the occurrence of the problem: it's either the laptop, or the newer kernel (well, or both). The issue only presented itself with the most recent kernel 4.4.0-53-generic (regardless of the distribution release), while the machine with an older kernel 3.13.0-101-generic is doing well.

Now, to isolate the culprit, I could boot the laptop with an older kernel (3.19.0-77-generic) via the boot loader and see if the issue appears again.
However, I would like to speed up the process of isolating where the weak link is. I am somewhat short of time and cannot put the laptop to the test while I use it for work. And the freezes are or might be a bit situational...

In other words, while normally I'd just have tried and seen, now I would really minimize the risk of having a freeze at work. I could prefer not to spend time on fixing the laptop at all and leaving it at home. But obviously I would also like to know whether upgrading the kernel in any other machine means heading for troubles.

So eventually the question. Is there a way to induce some freeze-like situations intendedly so that I can test whether the culprit is the laptop as the kernel it is running on or the laptop as anything but the kernel?

I am aware that the question is a bit paradoxical, because I would aim to stress the system and use the failure to do so as a proof that the system is stable. But perhaps this is an acknowledged strategy.

And, preferably, this should be a quick test and suitable to a power user... otherwise the whole lot is not worth the bother in the first place.

Comment: http://www.tecmint.com/linux-cpu-load-stress-test-with-stress-ng-tool/

Comment: The [link above](http://www.tecmint.com/linux-cpu-load-stress-test-with-stress-ng-tool/) proposes high-load stress tests, whereas high-load is not the likely culprit here (most likely some issue with X?). Also from the source 'Though these tools are good for examining your system, they should not just be used by any system user.'